# Show that $[K(X):K(X^{p}, Y^{p})]=p^2$ and $[K(X):K(X^{p}, Y^{p})]_{i}=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't know how to prove the following:

Let $K$ be a field. Then we have the polynomial ring $K[X_{1}, ..., X_{n}]$ and the field of fractions $$K(X_{1}, ..., X_{n}):= \{f/g| f,g \in K[X_{1}, ..., X_{n}], g\neq 0\}\setminus \sim $$
$f_{1}/g_{1} \sim f_{2}/g_{2}$ means that $f_{1}g_{2}=f_{2}g_{1}$ in $K[X_{1}, ..., X_{n}]$.

i) Assume that $char(K)=p>0$ and $K \subset K(X^{p}) \subset K(X)$.  Show that $[K(X):K(X^{p})]=p=[K(X):K(X^{p})]_{i}$.

ii) Assume that $char(K)=p>0$  and $K \subset K(X^{p}, Y^{p}) \subset K(X,Y)$.  Use i) to show that $[K(X):K(X^{p}, Y^{p})]=p^2$ and $[K(X):K(X^{p}, Y^{p})]_{i}=1$.

For a finite field extension $K\subset L$ is $ [L:K]_{i}$ defined as  $[L:K]/[L:K]_{s} $ which is $1$ for $char(K)=0$ and $p^{e}$ for $char(K)=p>0, e\in \mathbb{N} $.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: $[K(X,Y):K(X^p,Y^p)] = $ ?  Do you know anything about the degree of inseparable extensions ? Does $K(X,Y)/K(X^p,Y^p)$ have a separable subextension ?

Comment: We just started with this topic in the lecture and I can't really grasp the concept yet to be honest. We had a few theorems but I don't see how they are supposed to help me.

Comment: Do you see how for any field $F$ then $F(X), F(X^p)$ are fields and $F(X)$ is a $p$-dimensional $F(X^p)$ vector space so $[F(X):F(X^p)] = p$ ? So you get that $[K(X,Y):K(X^p:Y^p)] $ $= [K(X,Y):K(X,Y^p)][K(X,Y^p):K(X^p:Y^p)]$ $=[K(X)(Y):K(X)(Y^p)][K(Y^p)(X)K(Y^p)(X^p)] = p^2$. Then look at the minimal polynomials of those latter extensions to show (if $char(K) = p$) they are purely inseparable. Finally think about towers of purely inseparable extensions.